# What is the word for the corner where ceiling and wall meet in a house?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, terminology

In a square room in a house, what is the word for the corner where one of the walls meets the ceiling?

I kept thinking it was a word like "eaves", but that turned out to be the overhang.  I have googled a few things, but most of it is irrelevant about topics like mold.

---

Edit, for clarity:

In math, two distinct planes may intersect on a line, and 3 distinct planes may intersect at a point.  Lines segments between two points are sometimes called edges.

I said "square room", but what technically meant was "cube room".

I said "corner where one of the walls meet the ceiling" because I was thinking of the phrase, "Stand with his nose in the corner."  I've heard the word "corner" refer to BOTH the line of intersection between two planes AND the point of intersection between 3 planes, when people talk about rooms.  As in, "Painting yourself into a corner."

I should have used the word "edge", because I've only heard "edge" referred to as the LINE of intersection between two planes.  I think of "edge" as a more specialized word, for someone doing graph theory or geometry.  "Edge" would have been a much better word to use in asking because of the reduced ambiguity.

To be most clear, the reason I accepted the answer is because of the word **crown**.  Crown can be used to distinguish the difference between the edges where the walls meet the ceiling vs where the walls meet the floor.

I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: What's wrong with "corner"? *A/The corner of the ceiling* sounds perfectly fine to me.

Comment: I was looking for a word to distinguish between the upper corners and the lower corners.

Comment: if you could explain why you need this  specific term it would help.

Comment: Look, overhang is on the outside of a house. Eaves are in attics. One wall does not meet a ceiling "in a corner". Typically, the corners of a room can be at the ceiling or on the floor. A corner is formed by two walls, either at the top or the bottom. I think you are mixing up the word corner and edges, in a Romance language. Crown molding is decorative. Do you mean: the edge, where the edge of one wall meets the ceiling? That is called the ceiling line or where the wall ***meets*** the ceiling.

Comment: Please show us an image of what you mean.

Comment: I would call it "the spider"s nest".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The terms **ceiling line** and **floor line** are used for the lines where the wall meets the ceiling and the floor, respectively. For example, the terms are used in the book [*Architectural Drafting for Interior Designers*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=tmKVAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA346&dq=%22ceiling+line%22+%22floor+line%22+architecture&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLz-jNqqvYAhVJ4oMKHfzaAVMQ6AEIMTAB#v=onepage&q=%22ceiling%20line%22%20%22floor%20line%22%20architecture&f=false) (by Lydia Sloan Cline):

[image]

To make it more clear, I drew this diagram in Paint:

[image]

You can use the term *cove* or *coving* for the concave arched molding at the junction of a wall with a ceiling.

The definition of [*coving*](https://www.britannica.com/technology/coving) from *britannica.com*:

> **Coving**, in architecture, concave [molding](https://www.britannica.com/technology/molding-architecture) or arched section of wall surface. An example is the curved soffit connecting the top of an exterior wall to a projecting eave. The curve typically describes a quarter-circle. The arched sections of a curved ceiling would be coving. Such a coved ceiling serves to join the vertical walls with a flat ceiling.

The definition of **cove** from [*Architect's Illustrated Pocket Dictionary*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=7PXEeoS88lQC&pg=PA122&dq=cove+architect+dictionary&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiYmY--sKvYAhVD4YMKHaSmCNwQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=cove%20architect%20dictionary&f=false) (by Nikolas Davies, Erkki Jokiniemi):

> **1** a curved underside or soffit
>
> **2** coving; a concave moulding of plaster, timber or plastics, fixed as a decorative covering at the meeting of ceiling and wall; any meeting of ceiling and wall treated in this way; a cove tile; see also cavetto.
>
> [image]

Note: In North America, the term *crown molding* is used for the molding at the junction of an interior wall and ceiling.

Comment: No, I'm sorry, this is not right. Crown molding is a piece of wood glued or nailed into the top or near the top of a wall. This is most definitely not " the corner where one of the walls meets the ceiling"

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question. The lines of a wall and ceiling are just the lines where they meet. Molding or coving is not found on most walls. It is extra, decorative. The OP's question is not about this, I don't think.

Comment: I understand what you are saying and I understand the question. What you posted is correct but I don't believe the OP actually meant that. I have the feeling the OP speaks French or Spanish and is now under the impression that where every wall meets a ceiling, there is molding. See what I mean??

Comment: @Lambie the word I needed was "crown", to distinguish the difference between the edges where the floors meet the walls against the edges where the walls meet the ceiling.  Thanks for your help!  These comments have helped me think about the issue quite a lot.

Comment: @r12 But that is where you are in error, if you will.  The edges where the walls meet the ceiling are not called crowns. Believe it or not, ***there is no word for where the floor meets the wall and the walls meets the ceiling***. Where the floor meets the wall, there is often ***trim*** or ***baseboard*** and where the floor meets the ceiling, there is ***molding*** (crown molding being one of them), But those are added to the place where they meet and are not the meeting of them. :)

Comment: @Lambie I was hoping there was some sort of construction or architecture word for it, but words like "crown" for the top and "skirt" for the bottom are good enough to distinguish them.  I'm not trying to write a dictionary, I'm just looking for names that create uniqueness of space that are more evocative (or maybe less clinical?) than mathematical precision, like "The top edge where the Southwest wall meets the ceiling".   (Also, thanks for providing me with more terms. "Trim" and "baseboard" haven't been mentioned yet, and this is helping me greatly draw connections between these concepts.)

Comment: @r12 Try this technical glossary: https://www.homeadvisor.com/r/carpet-and-flooring-glossary. Good luck! A skirt? Lordie, that's another thing altogether. There's always: **joint**. Not elegant, but a building word. Joint compound is used in all the places where walls, ceilings and floors meet.

Answer (score 2):

> The cornice area is where walls and ceilings join.

From [Home Design Directory](https://www.homedesigndirectory.com.au/construction/wall-ceiling-junctions.php)

Answer (score 1):

I'm a plasterer; it's called the arris (a junction where two flat surfaces meet).

> **[arris](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/arris)**
>   noun
>   ar·​ris | \ ˈa-rəs, ˈer-əs\
>   *plural* **arris** *or* **arrises**
>
> the sharp edge or salient angle formed by the meeting of two surfaces especially in moldings
>
> [Source: Merriam-Webster Dictionary]

And a [more detailed explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arris):

> In architecture, an **arris** is the sharp edge formed by the intersection of two surfaces, such as the corner of a masonry unit; the edge of a timber in timber framing; the junction between two planes of plaster or any intersection of divergent architectural details. Also the raised edges which separate the flutings in a Doric column.
>
> [Source: Wikipedia]

Comment: Hmmm. I think I'd only use the term arris for an external corner, not for an internal one.

Answer (score -1):

In Australia we're pretty bloody straight. What I mean is we call a spade a spade right? Cornices are the the decorative mouldings that run along the the join between the ceiling and the roof (interior). Exterior overhangs ONLY are called eaves. And the fellow above is  correct. Skirting boards are the joins where the door frames meet the well door frames. If you have picture frames as well. Good luck. IMHO they should be left wooden or stained according to the choice of paint you choose above the picture rail and below. No I'm not an architect and I'm not a painter.  Just a renovater. Oh BTW I do speak French but Arris is not a word I learned.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question that was asked.